# How to find Automorphism group of $\mathbb Z_q \times\mathbb Z_q$ where $q$ is a prime.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

I know that automorphism group of $\mathbb Z_q$ is $(q-1)$ because the group is cyclic and its generator's image determines the automorphism and we have exactly $(q-1)$ choices.

For $\mathbb Z_q \times\mathbb Z_q$ I was thinking that since the group is generated by $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ but couldn't think how to see the maps that would be automorphisms.

Comment: Any such map is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_q$-modules, i.e. of vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Comment: So the order is same as the order of GL$_{2}$($\mathbb{Z}_{q}$) i.e. (q$^{2}$-1)(q$^{2}$-q) ??

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edits to the question.

Comment: Wait, in saying $\mathbb{Z}_q$ are you referencing the additive group $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$ or the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^*$? I'm assuming multiplicative since your limiting $q$ to prime numbers, correct?

Comment: Correct, HumbleStudent. You get the group of invertible 2x2 matrices over $\Bbb{Z}_q$.